# (Python3) Storing a 10x10 game map on a python array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, 2d

How do I store a 10x10 (100 unit) game map on a 2D python3 array?

Here is my current code:

```
53    worldMap = [[13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13], [13, 13, 13, 
                    13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13]]
236    porq = 0
237 genX = 0
238 genY = 0
239 
240 #world generator
241 while not 13 in worldMap:
242     porq = porq + 1
243     genIncoming = randint(1, 12)
244     worldMap[genX][genY] = genIncoming
245     genX = genX + 1
246     genY = genY + 1
247 print(worldMap)
```

Is throwing the error:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "python", line 244, in 
>   IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Can you put line numbers on the code? The traceback says line 244 but we don't know which part that is since this is just a snippet.

Comment: line 244 is worldMap[genX][genY] = genIncoming

Comment: I added line numbers

Comment: OK check the last part of my answer if you want a tldr. Gives you an easy way to do it without having to worry about multiple for loops and stuff. Also as was said in another answer, you are increasing both your column and row indices, so you're acessing elements in a diagonal. Also, your while condition is `while not 13 in worldmap` which is always false, because first off `worldmap` doesn't change, and second off, it contains a list of lists of 13s, not the number 13 itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need nested two-level for-loop to go through the map. What you had only generates block on the diagonal of the map, i.e. you are generating map for (0,0), (1,1), (2,2), ...., which also explains the index out of range error.

Try this

```
for genX in range(10):
    for genY in range(10):
        worldMap[genX][genY] = randint(1, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

So from your current question content, we cannot tell what exactly is your overall end goal. I am going to work under the assumption that you want an `n x n` matrix to be represented in Python, and have some sort of numbers in there. I'm going to fill this matrix with the number `13` and you can change it up as you need.

A matrix is basically rows and columns, something like this

```
13 13 13
13 13 13
13 13 13
```

This is a `3x3` matrix, with 3 rows and 3 columns.

I can represent the matrix with a collection of collections (list of lists, tuple of tuples, list of tuples, etc.) where each internal collection represents a row.

I'm not going to use a matrix of the size you want, because you need to be able to figure it out, I'll go with `5x5`.

This is what a `5x5` matrix would look like in Python list terms

`[[13, 13, 13, 13, 13], [13, 13, 13, 13, 13], [13, 13, 13, 13, 13], [13, 13, 13, 13, 13], [13, 13, 13, 13, 13]]`

To make this, I could do something shorter

`[[13 for column in range(5)] for row in range(5)]`

Now, you want a matrix, a collection of collections may be a bit unnecessary and slow, let's try using this library in Python called `numpy`. You'll have to install it either from the source, through Python code, or pip or some other tool, look it up.

Let's say I have my old collection of lists, now I don't want to use this because it's unnecessary and a bit confusing to look at it. I have to write in my own code to print it out correctly as a matrix, do matrix operations on it, etc. Why not use something that wraps that up for me, like a [numpy matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)?

```
import numpy as np

matrix_of_13s = np.matrix([[13 for column in range(5)] for row in range(5)]])
```

Let's say I need to access an element at row 3 and column 4. In my collection of collections, this means I need to get the third row and then the fourth element inside that. This translates to

`collection_of_13s[3][4]`

If I want to run through all the elements I'll use @thekingofkings' answer, except of course in this case with 5 rows and 5 columns.

```
for row in range(5):
    for column in range(5):
        print(collection_of_13s[row][column])
```

Now although this works, this isn't what I want. What I really want is a grid of 13s with my dimensions. Therefore why not use a numpy matrix like so?

```
matrix_of_13s = np.matrix(collection_of_13s)
for element in np.nditer(matrix_of_13s):
    print(element)
```

Which will go through every single element in the matrix, left to right in order of rows.

You'll also notice as your scale of your project grows, numpy is more efficient and easier to use, [for a reason](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/internals.html).

I also want to mention one more option which is a super simple concept, and you don't need any collection of collections or numpy. Just use a 1D array to represent your grid. This concept is actually used in principle component analysis of images, but that's unrelated.

Essentially, a grid of 13s becomes just a normal list

```
[13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13]
```

The new index of any element will be `(column +1)*(row)`. There's a mathematical proof and explanation of this but I don't want to find it right now lol.